# ASP MVC 5 - How session works on authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

as far as I know session variables are based on the context of http session established between the browser and the server.

In my application I would use the specific authenticated session: I would load a customer detail for the session based on the authentication. In particular I would get a new "session" every time i do the logout->login.

How can I accomplish that using ASP Mvc? (and perhaps ASP identity/owin).
My dream should be to configure a new istance of a session container for the entire auth session, not the http one.
Roberto

Comment: in the title you say `ASP MVC 5` and then as a tag you say `asp-classic` ... what is then?

Comment: sorry, I did a typo error

Answer (score 0):

A really easy answer is that you create a new MVC Project and choose to use *Forms Authentication*

[image]

then choose `Individual User Accounts`

[image]

After the project is created, check the `AccountController.cs` file as well the action views and see for yourself what's going on...

if you want a **step by step** follow up, just add a breakpoint in the `Login` Action (line 69) and run the web application and do the login... you can then inspect all variables, cookies and sessions.

If, you simply want to know the Authentication flow, there are several blogs and tutorials out there, I would point out a screencast that you can find in the [ASP.NET MVC website](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and check out those Pluralsight videos that are in the right side of that website.

Comment: HI, I know form authenticatio, my question is: how can I obtain a session variable for the life of the authentication instead of the life of the http session?

Comment: you don't, you get the `session` for the lifetime of the `HttpSession`, if you have the sessions with time scaling, each time the user requests something to the server, the session is updated, and it will be the job of the `Logout` action to dispose that sessions. If you want the session to expire sooner, just short the time of the session.